# How to customize ionic push notification like Incomming call?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am creating an app for video calling ,I am using ionic 5 and FCM to get notification but i hvae to customize notification like an incomming call

**Thanks In Advance**
and sorry for my bad English

`this.platform.ready().then(() => {

```
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
    console.log('backgroundMode activate');
    
  });
  this.startService();
  FCM.getToken().then(token => {
    console.log(token);
    this.storage.set('DeviceId', token);  
  });
 
  
  // ionic push notification example
  FCM.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
      if (data.wasTapped) {
      console.log('Received in background');
      this.router.navigate([data.landing_page]);
    } else {
      console.log('Received in foreground');
      this.router.navigate([data.landing_page]);
    }
  });    

  // refresh the FCM token
  FCM.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
    console.log(token);
  });
  
});
this.platform.resume.subscribe((e) => {
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  });
this.authenticationService.authState.subscribe(state => {
  if (state) {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
});
```

}`

Comment: you can detect notification is for incoming call. open application programmatically with incoming call page.

Comment: can i run code when app is closed?? and how can i detect fcm notification ??

Comment: what is your current code. share you notification code. There should be a event something like:  `onReceived` or something like that. depends which plugins you are using.

Comment: { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic';